# jquery multiple buttons to display same form is triggering forms for all buttons with one button click

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I'm new to jquery. For building a social media website,wherein you would see multiple profiles on a single page,there is a button on every profile which when clicked should display a comment box.For this I used [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SRw67/) code and tried to modify it in such a way that I can open the same form on every comment button click. But it turned out to display all the forms with one button click where as I want only one form to be opened when I click on a button. Please help me resolve this issue.

[This is how my form opens when I click on a single button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyNT4.jpg)

Below is my jQuery logic.

```
function deselect(e) {
    $('.pop').slideFadeToggle(function () {
        e.removeClass('selected');
    });
}

$(function () {
    $('.contact').click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            deselect($(this));
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $('.pop').slideFadeToggle();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('.close').on('click', function () {
        deselect($('#contact'));
        return false;
    });
});

$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function (easing, callback) {
    return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' },  'fast', easing, callback);
};
```

HTML

```
<div class="messagepop pop">
    <form method="post" id="new_message" action="/messages">
        <p><label for="body">Enter your comment  below</label><textarea rows="6" name="body" id="body" cols="35"></textarea></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="commit" id="message_submit" /> or <a class="close" href="/">Cancel</a></p>
    </form>
</div>

<button href="/contact" class="contact btn-comment">
    <img class="commentImg" src="msg.jpg" alt="submit" />
</button>
```

CSS

```
.commentImg {
    padding: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.btn-comment {
    border: 0; 
    background: transparent;
    float: right;
}
a.selected {
  background-color:#1F75CC;
  color:white;
  z-index:100;
}

.messagepop {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  border:1px solid #999999;
  cursor:default;
  display:none;
  margin-top: 15px;
  position:absolute;
  text-align:left;
  width:394px;
  z-index:50;
  padding: 25px 25px 20px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-indent: -15px;
}

.messagepop p, .messagepop.div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
  margin: 8px 0;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to only `toggle` the parent `div.pop` ,

So it should be done using `closest()` as follows,

```
//toggle only parent!
$(this).closest('.pop').slideFadeToggle();
```

You should modify your function as follows,

```
$(function () {
            $('.contact').click(function (e) {
                if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {

                    deselect($(this));
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                    //toggle only parent!
                    $(this).closest('.pop').slideFadeToggle();
                }
                return false;
                });

            $('.close').on('click', function () {
                deselect($('#contact'));
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Also you need to update your `deselect()` also,

```
function deselect(e) {
            e.closest('.pop').slideFadeToggle(function () {
                e.removeClass('selected');
            });
        }
```